# Using axios in a javascript function without global variables

Tags: javascript, function, axios

I'm trying to understand how to use axios (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.17.0/axios.js) within a function to talk to my own backend to get some data.

The code below works.

I need to define a global variable outside of the function to catch the result.

If I move the variable *myresponse* into the function, I can no longer catch the reply.

How can I avoid the global variable?

```
var myresponse = "xxx"

function getTimeData() {

    axios.get('/time')
    .then(function (response) {

    console.log(response.data);
        myresponse = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        myresponse = "error";
    });

    return myresponse;

}

console.log(getTimeData())
```

For this example I run a local server at "/time" that returns a timestring.

Answer (score 1):

Global variables can be used inside axios. As axios uses AJAX you should not return outside axios.

```
var myresponse = "xxx"

function getTimeData() {

    axios.get('/time')
    .then(function (response) {
        myresponse = response.data;
        return myresponse;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        myresponse = "error";
        return myresponse;
    });
}

console.log(getTimeData())
```

This will work. 
Even in your code while logging myresponse will not be set but after receiving response it will be set to response.data.

---

A part of my vue code which works fine. Note that after created this.users does not immediately get the value in res.data but it will contain res.data once axios sends the req and receives it.

```
var HTTP = axios.create({
            baseURL: URL,
        })
methods:{
                getUsers(){
                    return HTTP.get('/users/admin')
                },
                deleteUsers(user){
                    HTTP.post('/users/admin',{
                        id : user._id
                    })
                    .then(()=>{
                        this.getUsers()
                    })
                }                   
            },
            created(){
               this.getUsers().then(res=>{
                   this.users = res.data;
               })
            }
```

Comment: Thanks. This still uses a global `var myresponse = "xxx"`outside of the function. My question is how to avoid that global.

Comment: then return the axios request in a function and use promises for that

Comment: I tried that, but got  `[object Promise]` as a return value instead of the time. I don't know, how to get the return values of promises yet...

Comment: create a variable in your promise and then return the variable inside the promise itself then(res){ var new = res.data; return new;}

Comment: That will not work. getTimeData().then(res=>{
                       this.myresponse = res.data;
                   }).will work but still this will be asynchronous and has the same effect as passing the global variable inside the function.

Comment: Can you type that into your original answer with the variable names from the example? I have problems getting this to work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167029/discussion-between-576i-and-prajval-m).

Answer (score 1):

If your final desire is log the value why do you need a separate variable? Just do it in your function. With async/await:

```
const getTimeData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get( "/timer" );
        console.log( response.data );
    } catch ( error ) {
        console.log( error );
    }
};

getTimeData();
```

If you want to use the returned value somewhere else, use it again directly in your function:

```
const getTimeData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get( "/timer" );
        return somethingElse( response.data );
    } catch ( error ) {
        return errorHanlder( error );
    }
};

getTimeData();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to collect the data from axios you could always just wrap the return.

```
var result;
function getTimeData() {
    return axios.get('/time')
}

getTimeData()
.then(function(res) { 
  result = res.data;
  console.log(result);
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err)
});
```